# How can I trigger an AC output ON when an AC input is OFF?

Tags: ac, switching

I have a low power 24V AC circuit powering some motorised ball valves for switching water on and off. Several of the valves are 2-wire auto-return meaning that presence of an AC signal will open the valve, and absence of an AC signal will close the valve (ie. via a spring). 
One valve however is 3-wire and requires an AC signal between one wire & ground to open and an AC signal between the other wire & ground to close.

In effect, I'm trying to replace the relay in the following circuit with discrete components:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXXudu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The closest I've been able to get to a solution here is to take the switched AC input, convert to DC (ish) with a Diode Rectifier & Capacitor, then use this to trigger an inverted Transmission Gate but this feels overcomplicated and I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: What's wrong with using a relay? It really is the obvious choice in the absence of any other unusual requirements.

Comment: use the other side of the relay; they have NO and NC terminals.

Comment: @DaveTweed Fair. Mainly because I don’t have one in my stock box. Obviously I can buy one if that’s really the best answer.

Comment: If silent operation or increase of lifetime is your concern then a solid-state relay might be the solution. There are types where the input is an AC voltage. Other types can switch up to 200A.

Comment: @dandavis I’m trying to avoid the use of a relay here if possible.

Comment: @MarkusHufschmid all the SSRs I’ve ever seen are NO, do they come in NC (to invert the input)?

Comment: you could make your own AC SSR to meet your needs; your triac is always on except when enough current is robbed from the gate, perhaps by another triac driven by the input ac signal...

Comment: @dandavis **looks up triac** yes, that seems like the knowledge I’m missing here.

Comment: @DaveTweed I’m pretty sure I was reading your answer earlier but it appears to be gone now. Is it just me?

Comment: I deleted it because it had a fatal flaw. Replaced with a different design now.

Comment: you may be overlooking one detail ... the valve solenoids may be rated for only low duty cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just as an academic exercise, here's one way to achieve what you want. The transistor circuit inhibits passing current to the motor if there is also voltage on the control input (R1). Otherwise, the pass transistor behaves as a \$\frac{100 \Omega}{\beta}\$ resistor. Two bridge rectifiers allow it to work on both halves of the AC cycle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLiCov.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Select a transistor for Q2 that can handle the motor current.

Equivalent circuit for positive half-cycle:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsRnlD.png)</sup>

Equivalent circuit for negative half-cycle:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjqqQi.png)</sup>

Comment: Very clever  Without those two “equivalent circuits” I’d struggle to understand that at all..

Comment: Yes, I had to draw them out for myself to make sure I hadn't made another blunder.

Comment: Falstad simulation here: http://tinyurl.com/yar7amqq

Comment: That's ingenuity, Dave!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

[image]

The relay is avoided by having an SPDT switch for SW1.

Comment: I only have Live, Ground, and Switched Live available. The circuit diagram is just an expression of the problem.